# CakePHP 3 composer missing files

Tags: composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I updated my CakePHP 3 project via composer. I use the cake app skeleton. After update, my app gave me error messages about deprecated session helper. I checked the cakephp/cakephp github repository and in /src/Controller folder there are files like ComponentRegistry.php what I do not have in my project.

I am confused. Why composer did not sync these?﻿

Comment: Are you sure that you are comparing the appropriate branches/tags, and your local `app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller` folder instead of your `app/src/Controller` folder?

Comment: @ndm I use the same composer.json as the app skeleton. These files are not in the app repo but they are there in the cakephp repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the development version of CakePHP 3.1. In such version, the Session helper was deprecated. I would recommend setting your project to only work with the stable releases.

Comment: No, my composer.json is the same as in the app skeleton repo. "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.16",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.0",

Comment: you probably have a plugin or another dependency pulling the 3.1 branch

Comment: Thanks It was a plugin.